# htaccess url and subfolders

Tags: html, .htaccess

I got some problems with loading pages exp. when I open a page with `www.domain.com/dogs` it show up and when I'm trying it to open like `www.domaing.com/dogs/` I get a **`404`**. Same problem with sub-folder pages.

On my `public_html` I got a `index.html` and other 4 HTML pages. on my sub-folder same setup but translated.

I'm using an `.htacces` file in both folders which contain this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow a `/` in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you want to have the same rule work for folders (e.g. dogs/small-dogs.html), use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?:^|/)([^\.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: i tried to add this but it i still get 404. its there another solution to solve it?

Comment: @josen Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file? You can also try clearing your browser cache. If dogs.html exists and the original rule worked for www.domain.com/dogs, this should work for www.domain.com/dogs/.

Comment: after clearing the browser no it works with www.domain.com/dogs/. thanks! (using your .htaccess)

I still get 404 when im trying with exp. www.domain.com/dogs/small-dogs/.  (small-dogs.html in sub-folder) and same when im trying with www.domain.com/cats/. (cats.html in public html folder)

i need another rule to add?

Comment: @josen The updated answer will work for www.domain.com/dogs/small-dogs/. www.domain.com/cats/ should work though. If it doesn’t, that’s probably from something else. The server may not be able to find the file.